# What does the s() predicate do in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have been trying to learn Prolog, and am totally stumped on what the predicate s() does.
I see it used often and there is so little resources on the internet about Prolog that I cannot find an answer.

Ex.

```
    /* sum(Is,S) is true if S is the sum of the list of integers Is.           */
    sum([],0).
    sum([0|Is],S):-sum(Is,S).
    sum([s(I)|Is], s(Z) ):-sum([I|Is],Z).
```

Comment: What version of prolog interpreter do you use?

Comment: I use: SWI-Prolog version 5.10.1 for amd64

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`s/1` does not do anything in itself, and it's not really a predicate. They are just terms, a representation of the successor of their argument. So, `s(0)` is used to represent the successor of `0` (i.e. `1`), `s(s(0))` is used to represent the successor of `s(0)` (i.e. `2`), and so on and so forth. They are so widespread in Prolog because Prolog is quite fine a language to perform symbolic computation, whereas even simple arithmetic operations feel clunky, meaning that they are not seamlessly integrated with the programming paradigm.

Comment: This explains, very well, why the output of my programs using s/1 were so strange. Thank you very much, great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

s/1 stands for successor. It's used to represent numbers in a logically accessible ways.

Comment: That makes sense thank you very much! However when I try run a program count that uses s/1 I get strange output in the form of: 
?- mycount(a,[a,a],N).
N = s(s(0)) ;
N = s(0) ;
N = s(0) ;
N = 0 ;
false.

Answer (score 0):

It is Prolog-implementation specific. It refers to a successor-predicate, see [this](http://old.nabble.com/Newbie-confusions,-re%3a-Successor-function--Peano-arithmetic--counting.-td26950031.html) for some more info

Comment: `s(X)` is not implementation specific. It's an arbitrary functor. Try `t(X)` or `succ(X)` in its place.