# Undefined procedure s/1 predicate

Tags: prolog

I am taking a beginner prolog course. We are supposed to use swi-prolog, here's what mine says

```
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 3,856 bytes
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.10.4)
```

We are asked to develop the arithmetic predicate add(X,Y,Z). using the successor s(X) [= X+1] functor. This predicate fails on my machine with the following error:

```
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: s/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Does anyone have a solution? Must I downgrade my swipl, maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SWI-Prolog it's fine, but you misunderstood the assignment. You must write your definition of add/3, using instead of usual numbers the Peano representation, where, for instance, 2 become s(s(0)). You could search for similar questions, for instance I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310531/874024) to help understanding actual Prolog execution in the very same context you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to downgrade your interpreter version because `s/1` isn't an actual predicate (that's why you are getting this error). `s/1` just stands for "successor" as you already know, and it's used to represent numbers in a recursive way.

> The natural numbers in Prolog are built from two constructs, the
>   constant symbol `0` and the successor function `s` of arity 1. All the
>   natural numbers are then recursively given as `0, s(0), s(s(0)),
>   s(s(s(0))), ...`. We adopt the convention that s<sup>n</sup>(0) denotes the
>   integer *n*, that is, *n* applications of the successor function to
>   `0`

*[Sterling L., Shaphiro E., "The Art of Prolog", 2nd ed. - MIT Press]*

I think you'll find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197088/what-does-the-s-predicate-do-in-prolog) interesting.